# php mbstring mcrypt mysql login issue

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mcrypt, mbstring

I feel like I'm losing my mind. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I built an oop login/registration system following this tutorial [PHP OOP Login/Register system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc)

Everything was working perfectly until yesterday.
I had to rebuild apache/php to install the mbstring extension.

I'm a complete noob so please be patient with me.
I was able to track down what's happening.

The salt that is being stored in MySQL no longer works to verify the user's password.

password field in MySQL is varchar(64) with utf-8_general_ci collation

salt field is varchar(32) with utf-8_general_ci collation

Here are the relevant functions that handle the login/registration:

Hash.php

```
class Hash {
    public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
        return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
    }

    public static function salt($length) {
        return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
    }

    public static function unique() {
        return self::make(uniqid());
    }
}
```

Register.php

```
$user = new User();
$salt = Hash::salt(32);
try {
    //SIGN UP USER
    $user->create(array(
        'email' => $remail,
        'password' => Hash::make($pass, $salt),
        'salt' => $salt,
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'bname' => $bname,
        'addr' => $addr,
        'city' => $city,
        'state' => $state,
        'zip' => $zip,
        'phone' => $bphone,
        'djoined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    returnErrorWithMessage($message);
}
```

User.php

```
public function create($fields = array()) {
    if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
        $input = $this->_db->errorz();

        $output = implode(', ', array_map(
        function ($v, $k) {
            if(is_array($v)){
                return $k.'[]='.implode('&'.$k.'[]=', $v);
            }else{
                return $k.'='.$v;
                }
            }, 
            $input, 
            array_keys($input)
        ));

        throw new Exception($output);
    }
}
```

checklogin.php

```
public function login($email = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {

    if(!$email && !$password && $this->exists()) {
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    } else {
        $user = $this->find($email);

        if($user) {
//This line fails >> if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {

                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                ...
                ...
                ...

            }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

I haven't changed anything other than installing the mbstring extension.
Why don't the passwords match??? It was all working great before yesterday.

The Hash function is the same for generating and inserting into the db and for hashing the user password on the login screen for comparison.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not use password_hash and password_verify functions? BCrypt is better than SHA256 for password storage for many reasons. Also creating your own salt is a bad idea in general.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: hey @Kaylined and zaph thanks for taking the time to go through all my crap. Quick question... if I use the password_hash function with its default salt, how do I store that salt into the db? or is it no longer needed to be stored separately?

Comment: The salt is automatically created and stored alongside the Hash in the same string, so you only need 1 field in the database, the password_hash and password_verify functions handle the rest.

Comment: @Kaylined gotcha... working on implementing it right now. However I still have my concern regardless of the algo used... what caused my old pass/salt combo to not match anymore after installing mbstring?? Any ideas?

Comment: Not too sure; would have to see var_dump for $user in the checklogin.php  as I believe that's where your error is originating.

Comment: this is killing me slowly... so I switched to password_hash and password_verify and it still won't work. when creating the user I use 'password' => password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), when logging in I use if (password_verify($password, $this->data()->password)) { and still no luck :( I trully believe mbstring is somehow to blame. just can't figure out why

Comment: @Kaylined this is the data dump from checklogin: object(stdClass)#7 (12) { ["id"]=> string(2) "63" ["email"]=> string(23) "myemail@website.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$VmcSMo1dUH1keRNfkDj0ceS8mLHzCd6cM2s09mvFHt6YDA5J9dNoG" ["fname"]=> string(4) "Tony" ["lname"]=> string(6) "Whaawhaa" ["bname"]=> string(14) "Company Name" ["addr"]=> string(18) "123 N Street Rd" ["city"]=> string(7) "Chicago" ["state"]=> string(2) "IL" ["zip"]=> string(5) "60657" ["phone"]=> string(10) "1234567890" ["djoined"]=> string(19) "2017-01-20 14:43:13" }

Comment: mbstring shouldn't have anything to do with it, when using password_verify and password_hash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133678/discussion-between-kaylined-and-cnapsys).